# how to set supervisor to run a shell script

Tags: node.js, bash, docker, supervisord

Setting up a `Dockerfile` to install node prereqs and then set up supervisor in order to run the final `npm install` command. Running Docker in CoreOS under VirtualBox.

I have a `Dockerfile` that sets everything up correctly:

```
FROM ubuntu
MAINTAINER <<Me>>

# Install docker basics
RUN echo "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main universe" > /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get upgrade -y

# Install dependencies and nodejs
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y python-software-properties python g++ make
RUN add-apt-repository ppa:chris-lea/node.js
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs

# Install git
RUN apt-get install -y git

# Install supervisor
RUN apt-get install -y supervisor
RUN mkdir -p /var/log/supervisor

# Add supervisor config file
ADD ./etc/supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf

# Bundle app source
ADD . /src

# create supervisord user
RUN /usr/sbin/useradd --create-home --home-dir /usr/local/nonroot --shell /bin/bash nonroot
RUN chown -R nonroot: /src

# set install script to executable
RUN /bin/chmod +x /src/etc/install.sh

#set up .env file
RUN echo "NODE_ENV=development\nPORT=5000\nRIAK_SERVERS={SERVER}" > /src/.env

#expose the correct port
EXPOSE 5000

# start supervisord when container launches
CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord"]
```

And then I want to set up supervisord to launch one of a few possible processes, including an installation shell script that I've confirmed to work correctly, `install.sh`, which is located in the application's `/etc` directory:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /src; npm install
export PATH=$PATH:node_modules/.bin
```

However, I'm very new to supervisor syntax, and I can't get it to launch the shell script correctly. This is what I have in my `supervisord.conf` file:

```
[supervisord]
nodaemon=true

[program:install]
command=install.sh
directory=/src/etc/
user=nonroot
```

When I run the `Dockerfile`, everything runs correctly, but when I launch the image, I get the following:

```
2014-03-15 07:39:56,854 CRIT Supervisor running as root (no user in config file)
2014-03-15 07:39:56,856 WARN Included extra file "/etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf" during parsing
2014-03-15 07:39:56,913 INFO RPC interface 'supervisor' initialized
2014-03-15 07:39:56,913 WARN cElementTree not installed, using slower XML parser for XML-RPC
2014-03-15 07:39:56,914 CRIT Server 'unix_http_server' running without any HTTP authentication checking
2014-03-15 07:39:56,915 INFO supervisord started with pid 1
2014-03-15 07:39:57,918 INFO spawnerr: can't find command 'install.sh'
2014-03-15 07:39:58,920 INFO spawnerr: can't find command 'install.sh'
```

Clearly, I have not set up supervisor correctly to run this shell script -- is there part of the syntax that I'm screwing up?

Answer (score 23):

The best way that I found was setting this:

```
[program:my-program-name]
command = /path/to/my/command.sh
startsecs = 0
autorestart = false
startretries = 1
```

Answer (score 6):

I had a quick look in the source code for [supervisor](https://github.com/Supervisor/supervisor/blob/c7dc38bcb5c808d311b1a80ed13a8667a17ca24f/supervisor/process.py#L118) and noticed that if the *command* does not contain a forward slash `/`, it will look in the *PATH* environmental variable for that file. This imitates the behaviour of execution via shell.

The following methods should fix your initial problem:

1. Specify the full path of the script (like you have done in your own answer)
2. Prefix the *command* with `./`, i.e. `./install.sh` (in theory, but untested)
3. Prefix the *command* with the shell executable, i.e. `/bin/bash install.sh`

I do not understand why `user=` does not work for you (have you tried it after fixing execution?), but the problem you encountered in your own answer was probably due to the incorrect usage of [*su*](http://linux.die.net/man/1/su) which does not work like *sudo*. *su* will create its own interactive shell and will therefore hang while waiting for standard input. To run commands with *su*, use the `-c` flag, i.e. `su -c "some-program" nonroot`. An explicit shell can also be specified with the `-s` flag if necessary.

Answer (score 5):

think I got this sorted: needed the full path in `command`, and instead of having `user=nonroot` in the `.conf` file, I put `su nonroot` into the `install.sh` script.

Comment: edit: no dice, looks like it's hanging on `INFO success: install entered RUNNING state` but not exiting the script.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue too. For me, the root cause was failing to set the shebang line. Even if the script can run in bash fine, for supervisord to be able to `exec()` it, it has to begin with e.g. `#!/bin/bash`.